# Inheritance on Hibernate objects without table mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa

I want to use hibernate objects in project as defined below.

```
@Table(name = "Parent")
class Parent{

     int id;
     String name;

}

@Table(name = "Child")
class Child extends Parent{
     String schoolNo;
}
```

But in the database;
There is no relation with these two table.

Parent tables columns are; id, name

Child tables columns are; id, name and schoolNo

If I use

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

when I send a query for Parent object, hibernate use UNION on Child and Parent tables but I want to select from only Parent table.

And if I use

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
```

hibernate wants a discriminator column.

I need hibernate sends select query for each class to its table.

Best regards.

Comment: Why are you defining an inheritance strategy when there is no relationship between the tables?

Comment: I understood your thought about a silly architecture. Actually these are not table. These are views generated a lot of table combinations. Same fields but data cames from really different tables. Actually result objects are same for developer with a little difference. I hope explanation is clear.

Comment: Have you tried just not using @Inheritance?

Comment: "Not Using"'s behavior is same as SINGLE_TABLE strategy

Comment: How about this: don't make Child a subclass of Parent. Instead, make an interface that they both implement; Hibernate will completely ignore the relationship, and operations like 'new Child() instanceof ParentInterface` will work.

Comment: I also thought about interfaces but these classes used by some generators on the GWT side and used by some reflection codes. Convertors sometimes convert a child object to parent object and parent object to child object.

Comment: What are the ID columns? How are they defined in the code, and what are they in the database?

Comment: The database model is a bit complex. I'm very grateful for your solutions but the problem is "How can we build a inheritance mechanism  on this situation". I need "is a" relationship on JAVA side but not need on database side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TABLE_PER_CLASS is the correct strategy here.

It's odd that Hibernate generates a union query over both tables, but that should still work. The subquery over the wrong table won't find anything, so the results will be correct. This sounds like a bug in Hibernate's query generation for subclasses.

Comment: it looks like true but "won't find anything" is not really true. As I said before these are views and uses some shared tables to query and I tried and really listed values from both tables.

Comment: That could only be the case if the same ID is used for both a parent and a child. That should not be the case. Is that happening?

Comment: Then i think you may be out of luck. Your data model simply does not describe an inheritance relationship. There is no correct way to map an inheritance relationship onto it.

Comment: Indeed, my need is this. In heritance on java objects but not on Data model

Comment: You can't have that. You will have to find another way to solve the problem.

Comment: As you said, I gave up and extends all of the class from another class which is have no table on database.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation, I use `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` on the parent table.

See more info in the Hibernate docs: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1168

Comment: If I use JOINED strategy, hibernate generated SQL shown like "Select * from Parent, Child where Parent.id=Child.id(+) but I need only "Select * from Child" or only "Select * from Parent"